# how to get IntersectionObserver working with element bigger than viewport

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intersection-observer

[image]

I have a page with multiple sections, some small and some very big. As I scroll down, I want to know which section my nav is current hover.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/test-react-intersectional-observer-nav-knows-which-section-it-is-over-gyjpvj?file=/src/App.js

In my demo, I have it 95% working, except when I scroll over a section that is much bigger (height, "Section 4") than my viewport.

It should work as I'm observing all my sections over steps of different thresholds (`[0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, ... 0.99]`) and checking their y position if it's crossing under my nav (60px height) with `entry.boundingClientRect.top <= 60 && entry.boundingClientRect.bottom >= 60`.

It just seems like after "Section 3" the IO never fires for "Section 4" until "Section 5" comes into the viewport.

My IO functionality:

```
// IO: which sections under nav
useEffect(() => {
  const handleIntersection = (entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (
        entry.boundingClientRect.top <= 60 &&
        entry.boundingClientRect.bottom >= 60
      ) {
        console.log("navSection", entry.target.id);
        setNavSection(entry.target.id);
      }
    });
  };

  // 60px is the height of the nav
  const options = {
    root: document,
    rootMargin: "-60px 0px 0px 0px",
    threshold: [...Array(101).keys()].map((x) => x / 100)
  };

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection, options);

  sectionRefs.current.forEach((ref) => {
    observer.observe(ref);
  });

  return () => {
    observer.disconnect();
  };
}, [setNavSection]);
```

What a section looks like:

```
<div
  id="section1"
  ref={setRef(0)}
  className={`section ${
    activeSections.find((section) => section === "section1")
      ? "active"
      : ""
  }`}
>
  Content of Section 1
</div>
```

Ref:

```
const setRef = (index) => (ref) => {
  sectionRefs.current[index] = ref;
};
```

Comment: I too ran into this situation and expected intersection observer to offer a solution with little complexity. Here is a GitHub issue I found related to your question. https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/issues/124

If you found a graceful adaptation please share.